# Cross-domain cookies and signed applet

Tags: java, cookies, applet, signed-applet

Can a signed Java applet manipulate cookies from other domains? (e.g., with JSObject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A signed applet doesn't get elevated privileges in the browser so it won't be able to access the cookies. But it can read them from the disk if you know where to look.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, do you know if there is a standard way to get the path to the cookies, platform independently...?

Comment: That's very system and browser dependent unfortunately.