# Inject javascript in iframe using signed applet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, iframe, applet

My aim is to send cross-domain ajax request and I can't use JSONP (as it cannot make http post requests)

and then I tried to send request using applet but it's unable to access cookies out of it's domain - [Cross-domain cookies and signed applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721962/cross-domain-cookies-and-signed-applet)

Then I came to conclusion that if I can inject javascript into the iframe (which is of course not from the same domain) and I soon found out that browser doesn't allow to do so because of security reasons. It can work only when the iframe is from the same domain, protocol as the site itself.
[Injecting Javascript to Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353028/injecting-javascript-to-iframe)

Now I think if I can inject javascript in the iframe to send the destined ajax-request, and to inject javascript in iframe, I'm thinking of using signed java applet.

I tried searching a lot for some code/example, but to no avail.

Please let me know guys if it's possible to inject javascript in an iframe using signed applet.

Comment: Wow, too many things, what answer do you want? You cannot alter the content of an iframe, but you can grab it. You can use post with ajax.. but I don't understand that part. I don't think the applet is the best solution to anything...

Comment: If you just need to get around the cross-domain problem, it's pretty straightforward to set up a proxy service on your own server. Any back-end language will do the job in a couple of lines of code. Your server side script just needs to make a request for the cross-domain resource you require and pass it on to your frontend app.

Comment: the actual concern is to make an POST ajax-request to another domain as if it's appear from within that domain's iframe so that it can have proper Origin header.

Comment: @porfiriopartida so there's no way to inject javascript or send http request as if it is appearing from within the iframe (for proper http-header ORIGIN)